# how can I create a rectangular as big as the screen in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm trying to make a rectangular in XAML Xamarin Forms, how can I set Height and Width to be as big as the phone screen ? HeightRequest and widthRequest seems don't work
I want to make a thick transparent border around the camera frame so I want to make rectangular as big as the screen, how can i set these to fit all sizes of screens ?

```
<StackLayout>
    <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <xct:CameraView x:Name="cameraView"  CameraOptions="Back" CaptureMode="Photo" OnAvailable="CameraView_OnAvailable">
            <xct:CameraView.Behaviors >
                <xct:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding PhotoCapturedCommand}" EventName="MediaCaptured" />
            </xct:CameraView.Behaviors>
        </xct:CameraView>
        <Rectangle  HeightRequest="1*" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="Blue" Opacity="0.7" StrokeThickness="150"/>

    </Grid>

</StackLayout>
```

Comment: If you want to make a border around the cameraview you could always just use margin/padding or a Frame around the camera frame

Comment: @JuanSturla yes but this margin and padding will be a spaces and can't be coloured or transparent as I know

Comment: You can set the background color of the other element and then the space created from margin/padding will be "filled". But then again, using a Frame is a good alternative

Comment: I deleted the answer, so i don't misguide people. Do you want to achieve something like [this](https://support.schoology.com/hc/article_attachments/360024608273/Scan_your_code_Android.png)??

Comment: yes this is what I want, but cant understand how to set the width and height that can fit all screens in same ratio, like width of the rectangular is 50% from the screen width and same for height

Comment: You should use AbsoluteLayout then (or you can also use a Grid for that). I will write code in another answer

Comment: I edited the answer, please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Absolute Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout) has 2 great advantages:

1. As it name implies, the position/size of the element is absolute
2. You can "Stack" elements making layers

For this example, the CameraView will occupy 100% of the screen, and the "Mask" will be 50%.
These value are going to be proportional of the screen size (this is only an example).
Make sure to check for every screen that the image do not distort

```
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <xct:CameraView x:Name="cameraView"  CameraOptions="Back" CaptureMode="Photo" OnAvailable="CameraView_OnAvailable" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
        <xct:CameraView.Behaviors >
            <xct:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding PhotoCapturedCommand}" EventName="MediaCaptured" />
        </xct:CameraView.Behaviors>
    </xct:CameraView>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="White" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

You can put this code inside any other component if you want